# JSDOC: How to document inner variables of function

Tags: jsdoc, jsdoc3

Is there a way to have JSDOC to display variables inside of functions without using the **@namespace** annotation before the function?

I have made a small test object, but it will only display the inner variable **k** for the last function, which is declared as a namespace.  I thought using the **@memberof!** annotation and exact **@name** annotation would display the inner variable in the second method below called **diff**.  I am running jsdoc3 on the command with the options **--access "all" --explain**.

Here is the code for test object:

```
(function(){
    "use strict";
    /**
     * @namespace
     * @type {{}}
     */
    window.myFunctions = {};
    /**
     * Return the sum
     * @param {number} i
     * @param {number} j
     * @return {number}
     */
    window.myFunctions.sum = function(i, j) {
      /**  @type {number} */
      var k = i + j;
      return k;
    };
    /**
     * Return the difference i - j
     * @param {number} i
     * @param {number} j
     * @return {number}
     */
    window.myFunctions.diff = function(i, j) {
      /**
       * @inner
       * @memberof! window.myFunctions.diff
       * @type {number}
       * @name window.myFunctions.diff~k
       */
      var k = i - j;
      return k;
    };
    /**
     * Return the product
     * @namespace
     * @param {number} i
     * @param {number} j
     * @return {number}
     */
    window.myFunctions.multiply = function(i, j) {
      /** @type {number} */
      var k = i * j;
      return k;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

i noticed your code is within an IIFE, you should [read this issue](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/456)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [@module](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-module.html) and [@exports](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-exports.html) tags.

From the [documentation](http://usejsdoc.org/howto-amd-modules.html):

> If you define your AMD module as a function that returns an object
>   literal, use the @exports tag to document the module's name. JSDoc
>   will automatically detect that the object's properties are members of
>   the module.

So, your code example could be marked up like this:

```
/**
 * functions module.
 * @module my/functions
 */
(function(){
    "use strict";
    /**
     * @namespace
     * @type {{}}
     * @exports my/functions
     * @name myFunctions
     */
    window.myFunctions = {};
    /**
     * Return the sum
     * @param {number} i
     * @param {number} j
     * @return {number}
     * @exports my/functions
     * @name sum
     */
    window.myFunctions.sum = function(i, j) {
      /**
       * @type {number}
       * @exports my/functions
       * @name k
       */
      var k = i + j;
      return k;
    };
    /**
     * Return the difference i - j
     * @param {number} i
     * @param {number} j
     * @return {number}
     * @exports my/functions
     * @name diff
     */
    window.myFunctions.diff = function(i, j) {
      /**
       * @inner
       * @memberof! window.myFunctions.diff
       * @type {number}
       * @name window.myFunctions.diff~k
       * @exports my/functions
       */
      var k = i - j;
      return k;
    };
    /**
     * Return the product
     * @namespace
     * @param {number} i
     * @param {number} j
     * @return {number}
     * @exports my/functions
     * @name multiply
     */
    window.myFunctions.multiply = function(i, j) {
      /**
       * @type {number}
       * @exports my/functions
       * @name k
       */
      var k = i * j;
      return k;
    }
});
```